# bash: wso2ei-6.4.0-micro-integrator: command not found

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

Am trying to running in my `wso2-ei` container following the steps [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Sending+a+Simple+Message+to+a+Service+Using+the+Micro+Integrator#5002208c3dc24c30b8d232d4553a635f). Starting the Micro Integrator profile, I got bash:

> wso2ei-6.4.0-micro-integrator: command not found

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

follow following steps;

1. go to the [EI download page](https://wso2.com/enterprise-integrator/6.5.0#)
2. Choose Following option to download the binary file
   [image]
3. unzip the zip file
4. there is a file called `integrator.bat`; run it!

In case if you have downloaded and installed msi package, you have to go to `Start Menu -> Programs -> WSO2 -> Enterprise Integrator 6.4.0 Micro Integrator`. This will open a terminal and start the Micro Integrator profile.